# How to change status bar color with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Good evening guys.

I have a problem. I've been on flutter for quite some time. Here I have two AScreen and BScreen screens. For AScreen I would like a white color status bar with black icons. And for BScreen a red status bar with the icons in white. How to achieve this ??

I use flutter_statusbarcolo when I am on screen A the status bar is red I navigate to screen B the status bar is white but when I return to screen A the status bar keeps the color white (color of the screen B)

Comment: Please provide minimal code samples.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to change this on per-screen basis, do this on your `appBar` off the your screen's `Scaffold`.

Use

```
appBar: AppBar(
  backgroundColor: Colors.red, // status bar color
  brightness: Brightness.light, // status bar brightness
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor:Colors.white,),child: Scaffold(),)
```

Applies its effect only for the widget that you wrap.

Comment: I checked this. It should work unless your screen includes Appbar because appbar override the other styles!

Comment: Yes of course I have an appBar and I would like it to have the same color as my status bar

Comment: I use flutter_statusbarcolo when I am on screen A the status bar is red I navigate to screen B the status bar is white but when I return to screen A the status bar keeps the color white (color of the screen B)